# The others I know are genuine

Tags: punctuation

This sentence is shown in CGEL by Pullum at p 1085:

> (1) ***The others I know are genuine.*** [An example shown in CGEL]

The book says (1) is intended to mean:

> (2) ***I know the others are genuine.***

The book says (1) is not intended to mean:

> (3) ***The others that I know are genuine.***

In this CGEL example of (1), there are no commas around "I know" as in

> (4) ***The others, I know, are genuine.*** [Not an example shown in CGEL]

The book analyzed ***The others*** as a "prenucleus" noun phrase that was positioned to the left of the "nucleus" clause ***I know ___ are genuine***, where the gap represents the subject position.

Here're my questions.

Is (1) natural English when intended to mean (2) as claimed by CGEL?

If so, what's the difference between (1) and (4)?

Comment: What's wrong with (3) as a possible interpretation of (1)?

Comment: @Lawrence It's not that (1) cannot mean (3). It's just that CGEL intended (1) to mean (2), not (3), in the section quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, (2) is a valid interpretation of (1). Stress the word *know* and read the sentence in the following sense:

- I can only guess whether *this* sample is genuine, but the others I *know* are genuine.

The sense is that the speaker is emphasising that he knows that the others are genuine. The word *know* is central to (1). *Others* and *genuine* are details about that knowledge.

With (4), the emphasis is different; it's emphasising either *others* or *genuine*. The words "I know" are spoken more softly. The word *know* isn't central to (4). The parenthetical phrase "I know" can be removed altogether without changing the 'message' of (4).

---

Elaborating on (4): consider the following from an article entitled [Emphasis](http://changingminds.org/techniques/language/modifying_meaning/emphasis.htm). They took a sentence and, by just changing where the emphasis is placed, changed the message conveyed. I'm just focusing on the following example:

- Example: **Mary** had a little lamb
- Meaning: Mary, not Tom, had the lamb

Compare the 'meaning' part above with (4) in your examples. The parenthetical phrase is extra information; the part(s) emphasised are located elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is natural English to use  1 when you mean 2, though it has a tiny bit of an old-fashioned and formal air.

1 and 4 are almost equivalent, except that 4 has a bit of extra emphasis on the *'I know'* part, as though the speaker seeks to reassure the listener, while 1 has no special emphasis.

To understand, rewrite the sentences​ with 'I know' on the beginning.

1. I know the others are genuine.
2. I know, the others are genuine.

Here, you can see the extra emphasis on *'I know'.*

Answer (score 0):

(1) Specifically refers to the writer's knowledge of knowing the others. "The others" -that- "I know" is pretty much what it means without commas separating it. 
(1) Differs from (4) simply because (4) doesn't refer to the knowledge of knowing the others. Instead the "I know" in (4) acts more like "I'm sure."

I don't believe (1) means (2), either, for the same reasons, but it does convey the same message with less emphasis.

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. If you had taken the introductory tour and read the help you would have seen that here we're looking for answers of sufficient length that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.